# Why does my EV charger only draw 6 or 12 amps on a 20 amp circuit?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

It was installed in 2005 as part of a heavy-up.  It is on a 20 amp breaker with 12/3 wire.  I initially used it for yard tools.  Now, I am using it to charge my EV.  I am using a 5-15 plug.  I usually pull the expected 12 amps, but it often drops back to only 6 amps. Should replace the outlet?  Do they wear out?

Comment: What is a "heavy-up" please ?   Some sort of large upgrade to your power wiring?

Comment: And what was installed in 2005? The charger, or an outlet?

Comment: @Criggie a heavy up is usually replacing the main panel and increasing utility service at the same time. (Which I'm waiting for my electrician to do.) Typically additional circuits or other work (eg generator interlock) is done at the same time. Very common for US houses with original panels from 60s or earlier.

Comment: 12/3 and NEMA 5-15?

Comment: Your electric vehicle charger was installed in 2005?  What type of electric vehicle charges were even on the market in 2005?

Comment: By what communication channel do you expect your charger to obtain knowledge of your circuit rating? ;-)

Answer (score 12):

The outlet/receptacle is fine. The charger actually controls the charge rate--as the voltage on the battery increases or the battery temp the charge rate is reduced to increase overall battery life. If it charged at the full rate 100% of the cycle the battery life would be reduced and the chance of a fire is increased along with overcharging.

Your charger is operating properly and as it should.

Comment: Most EVs should easily be able to charge at 12 amps 240V (let alone 120V) up to almost full.

Comment: @jpa they absolutely can but doing this reduces the battery life. the charger in question is a level 1 , using a level 2 charger will reduce the battery life level 3 severely reduces the life. Level 1 is not discussed much because of the low level and by design it is the easiest on the battery but even then it is smart to reduce the rate to extend the life, my cell phone dose the same it calculates the time until needed and may take 6 hours to completely charge when it could charge in 1/2 hour, why because it extends the battery life and phones are not as hard on battery’s as EV’s are.

Comment: This answer concerns me because it arm-waves away as "taper" what could actually be a serious problem with series arcing at the socket - common with amateur installed sockets.  Charging at 1500W doesn't reduce battery life appreciably.  EV batteries are absolutely huge, so 1500W on an EV battery is like 15 watts on a normal car battery. By the time the taper on an EV battery is below 1500W, you are into the 99.9's% of charge.

Comment: @harper again I ask have you ever designed a charger or know the dynamics of high efficiency battery charging? Have a electrical license or degree in electronics? I am not a battery engineer but have worked professionally at discovery of battery failures and the reason behind them. I asked point to a white paper that says I am wrong, no you change the brand and say this one has it. As I mentioned Arizona some battery’s will only charge at a reduced rate due to the ambient temperature, this can be overridden at the expense of battery life but even level 3 changing has limits/ life consequences

Comment: @EdBeal While we're asking people about their credentials, have you ever owned an EV?

Comment: Undo unlike most I have wired many EV’s  that were permitted jobs and passed inspection.  Mostly level 2 the ones that only required a 20a branch circuit were installed under a minor inspection label no inspector (no a home owner can not get one of these only pros) part of each new type install is actually reading the mfg instructions how many have you read? I have read over a dozen different types. It takes nothing to own one , but a bit more to install one to code.

Comment: @Ed I know your ego is kinda wrapped up in this, but lots of experience doesn't mean currency in that experience. I feel you, though.  They really did a blank-slate redesign of the concept of how charging works.  They Elon Musk-i-fied the tech from stem to stern and **obsoleted everything we used to know**.  Thermistors in plugs, current limiting by PWM signal, water cooling batteries, *landing rockets and re-using them next week*, who saw any of that coming???  *It's good stuff though, I'll take it*.

Answer (score 11):

I doubt you would be complaining if current slackened at the very top of charge (>99%).

This suggests a possible problem: **overheating of the receptacle due to faulty connection** (e.g. series arcing) at the receptacle.  This is often caused by the socket being installed amateurishly, with incorrect torque on the screw terminals in violation of NEC 110.14.

However there is an easy way to fix this and triple your charge rate, given the "12/3" circuit to your garage.

### How EVSE charging works

The EVSE is not a charger.  It is simply a power gateway for the EV. The EVSE's job is to tell the EV how much utility current is available to draw.

All EVSE's are compatible *, and use the exact same signal protocol to communicate this allowable current.

* Tesla uses a different shaped plug. (there is no electrical difference).

The EV itself contains the charger, and it uses the signal from the EVSE indicating allowable charge current, plus its own onboard battery management system data, to determine charge rate/curve. However that won't be a limiting factor for you.

The EVSE has a NEMA 5-15 type plug.  That means it cannot assume it is in any larger than a 15A circuit.  If it had a NEMA 5-20 plug it could assume a 20A circuit.

Code requires that a circuit provide 125% of an EVSE's needs.  Therefore an EVSE can only authorize 80% of the known circuit capacity.  (This is why almost every plug-in appliance is no more than 1500W).

80% of 15A is 12A, hence the limit.

### Battery "top of charge" taper *is not a factor* at 1500W

The unit "C" indicates a battery's charge rate as a percentage of its capacity per hour.  So a 10 watt-hour battery charging at 5 watts is nominally 0.5 C, giving 2 hours to charge (1/0.5).  But in fact, batteries have a charge-rate curve, where they significantly slow down charging as they reach top of charge.  For instance, a 100KWH battery in a Tesla Model S can charge at 250 KW, or 2.5 C.  However that only works in the middle of charge, 20-80%. At the bottom and top of charge, it must slow battery charging to a lower "C" rate to avoid damage to the battery.

Now think about it. That 100k WH Tesla pack, charging at home on a level 2, 50A circuit, 10,000 watt level 2 EVSE... is running about 0.1 C - a tiny rate compared to the Supercharger rate.  Trying to run off a 1500W outlet would be 0.015 C - or 15/1000 of a C, or 66 hours to fully charge LOL.

Do we need to worry about taper charging when our max charge rate is 0.015 C?  The answer is "LOL no", it can go 0.015 C right up to 100%.  **And then, the charger shuts off.**

### You have a problem with your charging.

It is impossible for an appliance plugged into a circuit to know how many amps are being drawn by all the appliances on the circuit.  Wires don't reveal that and neither do breakers. Monitoring line voltage isn't very useful either, because there'd be no way to distinguish a loaded circuit from one simply with long wires.

Something is making the EVSE "throttle back".  I think Olivier's theory of a temperature sensor in the EVSE plug makes the most sense.  Plug heating is a serious problem, either from a worn-out socket, or from incompetent wiring to that socket.  Once I detected a warm plug on a dehumidifier, popped the socket out and found #12 stranded wire had been crammed into a socket "backstab" connection (made for #14 solid only). You find dumb stuff like that all the time.

NEC 110.14 requires small sockets be torqued to spec with a torque screwdriver, but nobody does it.

### Let's do this a better way.

Since you say 12/3 wire was used from the panel to the garage, and if I'm correct it's a "2-pole" 240V breaker with a built-in handle tie between the poles... This was actually wired as something we rarely see, called a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit (MWBC) aka shared neutral.

The simplest idea of the MWBC is that you connect 120V loads between one of the hots and neutral, and you do that twice, so you're getting two 120V "circuits" for the price of one.  And sure... that works.

However, MWBCs have a second very cool feature: You can *also* attach 240V loads to the two hot wires (and ignore neutral altogether if you don't need it... and you don't need it).  You can simply put a NEMA 6-20 socket right next to the NEMA 5-15 socket(s), and wire the 6-20 to black and red, ignoring white.  "That was easy"

The only hitch is, if you do that, the MWBC must be fed from one 2-pole breaker that is marked "Common Trip".  Check it, and if it's not, change the breaker.

Then you must reconfigure the EVSE to indicate it is on a 20A circuit. (It will figure out it's 240V, you don't need to tell it that).

If you are able to run 240V @ 16A, you'll be charging at 3840W (nominal 4000W) instead of 1440W (nominal 1500W). That's almost 3 times faster!  However, to run 16A you will need to turn off every other load in the garage while charging.

You could also voluntarily step down to 240V @ 12A, which is exactly twice the rate you're charging now (when it's working).

At these higher charge rates, you *might* see charge rate taper off as you get above 95% charge (but I doubt it - if you see that, still assume it's a problem!)

Lastly if you hook up the 240V outlet and see 0 volts on it, the circuit breaker is mis-configured in a way that is deadly to MWBCs (or rather, deadly to the house they're in). Stop using immediately and have it fixed!

### Reconfiguring the EVSE

**Portable "glove box" EVSE.**  First, if you are new to EVs, I know they give you a "portable, lump in the cord style" EVSE with the EV. It's not really meant to be your primary EVSE.  But if that's what you're using, you'll see that the "AC power plug" end is actually a **dongle** that unplugs from the rest of the EVSE.

You can go to the manufacturer and get a different dongle for NEMA 6-20 (or NEMA 6-15 if you'd prefer to throttle the amps to 12A so you can run other loads in the garage simultaneously; that's still 2x the charge rate you have now).

[Using](https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/charge-rate-reduced-wall-plug-temperature-high.236889/) silicon [magic](https://www.chevybolt.org/threads/changing-the-plug-on-the-evse.30903/), the [dongle](https://www.speakev.com/threads/putting-a-new-plug-on-an-evse-and-the-thermal-sensor-question.57161/) itself [tells](https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/heat-sensing-evse.29221/) the EVSE (and the EV) "I am a 20A socket, please run 16A" and "I am overheating, reduce current". You may notice a 4th wire in the dongle connection.

**Wall-mounted "permanent" EVSE**: Really, the glove-box EVSE is best left in the glove box for opportunity charging on the road.  Many people use a "mounted on the wall" EVSE unit which either plugs in or is hardwired into the house. This can be from any manufacturer - the Tesla plug difference can be handled by a $150 adapter.

With these wall mounts (plug or hardwired), the ampacity is a "DIP Switch" setting inside the EVSE. (or in rare cases, a wackadoodle WiFi network that can only be reached by some outlandish sequence you would never do naturally.)  You would need to flip the switch from "15A breaker" (12A) to "20A breaker (16A).  The EVSE itself will figure out the 120/240V voltage change.

### Wait. Hardwire the EVSE?

Yes. When dealing with wall-mount EVSEs, you have the option to use cord-and-plug, or to hard-wire (bypass cord and plug altogether and wire straight into a box).  This has several differences.

- No more plug or socket.  You know that overheat problem I think you're having? *That goes away*.  I mean you have to tighten the wire nuts correctly, but you now have 2 contact points instead of 6 that could fail.
- No need for **Stupid GFCIs**.  Most plug outlets in a garage *require* GFCI protection at an outlet or breaker.  In NEC 2020, 240V receptacles need this too, and that can only be done with a $100 Stupid GFCI breaker.  However, if you hardwire an EVSE, every EVSE already includes a ***smart*** GFCI which will automatically retry, and will alert you if it fails.

Comment: the wiring harness would require an additional 2 wires to detect the temperature at the plug according. Since there weren’t any extras how is it measuring the temp, a thermocouple takes 2 or more conductors depending on the type, a thermistor takes 2 wires , I guess it could be some type of RF type device but that would not be normal if it was a safety as they are required to be hard wired. With your opinions provided you forgot the reason for reducing the charge and it is to prevent over charging and this extends the battery life but according to you this is bunk where do you get this

Comment: @EdBeal Almost all of these glove-box portable EVSE's have exchangeable plugs so the same unit can talk to NEMA 5-15, 6-50, 6-20 or whatever.  https://shop.tesla.com/product/gen-2-nema-adapters The dongle itself has electronics on board so it must *at least* tell the EVSE the ampacity of the socket.  There is at least a 4th pin on the dongle-EVSE connector. Since you have at least that, adding more stuff is easy.  Just modern microelectronics cast into the molded case.  Might be fun to do a teardown of one.

Comment: it is not on the print there are no connections for it micro electronics or not there has to be a connection to monitor the plug and that is what the question asked and there are none so please with your long winded answer show me how your opinion could be or something that someone heard is accurate when the electrical schematics do not support your statements!

Comment: @EdBeal I think each of us is talking about a different thing entirely.  I assure you that in-plug temp sensors are real.  Here are some links. https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/charge-rate-reduced-wall-plug-temperature-high.236889/  https://www.chevybolt.org/threads/changing-the-plug-on-the-evse.30903/  https://www.speakev.com/threads/putting-a-new-plug-on-an-evse-and-the-thermal-sensor-question.57161/ https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/heat-sensing-evse.29221/  I haven't checked the White Book but I bet they're a UL requirement. Again we are talking about "glove box" EVSEs.

Comment: Great @harper you changed brands this is not a GM and it uses one of the methods I mentioned dang how did I know about them on some of the plugs the actual shape of the female end tells the charger what it is as I said I looked up the prime it did not have extra connections so the receptacle is fine, come on a 50% reduction in charging if it were the plug would melt it down just like so many extension cords that fail and melt, even an internet electrician should be able to see this.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: Would there be any regulatory problem having an RF temperature reporting mechanism along with a thermal safety shutoff, with the design intention that when the RF reporting mechanism is working the plug would never reach the safety shutoff temperature?

Comment: @supercat That is a question for UL.  The problem with RF that I see, is, you somehow have to get power to it. You don't want to be converting 120V to 5V inside a molded case plug, so that 5V is going to come on a dedicated "fourth" wire from the EVSE proper, (using AC mains earth as return) and then you'll just overlay your datacomm on that 4th wire, easy with modern electronics.  The microcontroller must tell the EVSE a) "I am a 20A plug, go 16A" and b) "I am getting hot, reduce".  It could do both things at once actually lol, it could be the actual source of the J1772 1KHz square wave.

Comment: You missed the 12/3 elephant in the circuit. If this is true it can be upgraded to 240v 20 amp while keeping other outlets on the circuit 120v. Though if it is a long run from the panel 240v 15 may be more appropriate to avoid voltage sag.

Comment: @Max good point, I missed that altogether! That is a game changer.

Answer (score 4):

Ed Beal's answer is accurate for most cases. However, I have read that some EVSEs (eg. the one shipped with the RAV4 prime) have a temperature sensor in the plug. So switching to 6 amp could be caused by overheating at the outlet. Outlets do wear out if used a lot and this can't be ruled out without checking if the plug gets too warm.

Comment: The rav4 onboard charger is only 12amp , the receptacle was installed in 2005 it would be possible for home owners grade receptacle to go bad , but more likely the charger is changing charging levels as heat will even a high ambient temp requires a slower charge rate I have never see a charger that measures the plug temp but it is well documented that battery heat is a critical item, do you have anything beyond you heard because it is not in the prints for the on board for the prime.

Comment: @EdBeal 12A at 120V is precisely what OP enquired about so it fits. And that's only 1.44 kW, a ridiculously slow charge rate even for the small battery of a plug-in hybrid (less than 0.1C). Although possible, it's unlikely that temperature would reduce charge rate further. That specific car also has an unusual charging pattern, as if it were measuring line resistance. I don't have hard evidence for any of it (don't own one) but these things would be good engineering to protect against typical misuse of the equipment which is bound to happen. So we can't entirely rule out a bad outlet.

Comment: And your opinion is it is ridiculously slow with no background to back this up Oliver? Have you built a battery charger ? Even nimH battery’s for tools have the smarts to do the same and as I said it extends the battery life, EV charging at 80% is reduced to extend battery life EV charged with only level 2 chargers had a 23% reduction in battery life. battery’s work best from 70-80f above this level the life is shortened this is from Green cars, but my experience comes from testing NimH computer battery’s after several laptop fires. This was done at several of the HP sites specific conditions.

Comment: @EdBeal I do have actual experience with other EVs. And yes, 1.44 kW is stupid slow for any EV, even a first gen Leaf with no battery cooling system. Search the internet if you won't take my word for it.